# How to train LSTM layer of deep-network

Tags: classification, neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm

I'm using a lstm and feed-forward network to classify text.

I convert the text into one-hot vectors and feed each into the lstm so I can summarise it as a single representation. Then I feed it to the other network.

But how do I train the lstm? I just want to sequence classify the text— should I feed it without training? I just want to represent the passage as a single item I can feed into the input layer of the classifier.

I would greatly appreciate any advice with this!

Update:

So I have an lstm and a classifier. I take all the outputs of the lstm and mean-pool them, then I feed that average into the classifier.

My issue is that I don't know how to train the lstm or the classifier. I know what the input should be for the lstm and what the output of the classifier should be for that input. Since they are two separate networks that are just being activated sequentially, I need to know and don't know what the ideal-output should be for the lstm, which would also be the input for the classifier. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best place to start with LSTMs is the blog post of A. Karpathy http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/. If you are using Torch7 (which I would strongly suggest) the source code is available at github https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn.

I would also try to alter your model a bit. I would use a many-to-one approach so that you input words through a lookup table and add a special word at the end of each sequence, so that only when you input the "end of the sequence" sign you will read the classification output and calculate the error based on your training criterion. This way you would train directly under a supervised context.

[image]

On the other hand, a simpler approach would be to use paragraph2vec (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) to extract features for your input text and then run a classifier on top of your features. Paragraph vector feature extraction is very simple and in python it would be:

```
class LabeledLineSentence(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def __iter__(self):
        for uid, line in enumerate(open(self.filename)):
            yield LabeledSentence(words=line.split(), labels=['TXT_%s' % uid])

sentences = LabeledLineSentence('your_text.txt')

model = Doc2Vec(alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025, size=50, window=5, min_count=5, dm=1, workers=8, sample=1e-5)
model.build_vocab(sentences)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    try:
        model.train(sentences)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will consider those. Do you have any advice towards the specific issue in my question— I have updated it.

Comment: I don't think that your described procedure would produce any results. In what will you train against the LSTM? I'm not sure I understand why would use an LSTM in this case for unsupervised feature learning for a whole sentence. Do you have any relevant literature on your approach I could help you with? This might be of your interest as well http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3584.

Comment: I will train the lstm based on a data set of past passages of text and their classes. I'm not intending to use unsupervised learning. I want to manually train it, but don't know how. Here is my implementation of the lstm and classifier without the machine-learning library, which I know works: http://pastebin.com/63Cqrnef the lstm has a function of deepActivate that activate the lstm and then the classifier as I mentioned in my quesiton. Here's something like what I am trying to implement: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html

Comment: but when I tried to activate them both as one network, I got undefined from each of the output layers. More on that is here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/159922/81435

Comment: Supervised is always preferred. So you have to follow my suggested approach. I ve never used synaptic, but there is no reason to implement your own lstm code. I would strongly recomend Torch7 as your framework. Now you can take the code from here: https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn and customise it to a many-to-one instead of many-to-many approach, which should be fairly easy if you read the blog post. In case you need help with the code feel free to open a new question.

Comment: My thing is I need to have this done in js. And the library came with an lstm build in. If you don't mind— could you explain how I could train the two networks in this case? You don't have to explain in terms of synaptic. Just, theoretically, what would you do to train the lstm and classifier so that the lstm's input corresponds with the classifier' output?

Comment: I tried making one network, but I believe the deep connections confused the library. Too many hidden layers. That is why I am doing this separate approach and wondering what I can do int his case theoretically so I can hopefully implement it.

Comment: You cannot train the two networks in a supervised way, the only way to train supervised in make them one with the way wrote in my answer, using a many-to-one lstm.

Comment: Thank you very much! You provided much more help than was required. Thanks for going above and beyond.